# LogicException in CryptKey.php line 44: Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

I followed the documentation and configured Laravel Passport as mention here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

but am getting the error

Key path "file://C:\wamp64\www\blog\storage\oauth-public.key" does not exist or is not readable

Comment: are you on windows ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For users using wamp on windows, download openssl from https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads and extract it. Add the path /bin to environment variables and then run

```
php artisan passport:install
```

Answer (score 2):

I had that error too, If you are on windows the command

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

needs openssl program, If you using xampp, then you already have that program on

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin
```

so add that path to system variables "if you need help with that just comment, I'll help you" after adding it run the command

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

and make sure that it worked by looking in your storage folder, you should find the missing .key files

Comment: Hi, yes I am on windows, wamp

Comment: well, I don't know the path to openssl.exe on wamp, but you can search for it, and if it doesn't exist, just download it, add it to whatever path you like and add that path to your system variables, then the command should work

Comment: BTW, when you add that path, next time you will not have to run this command again: php artisan passport:keys , php artisan passport:install will generate those keys

Comment: Yes, It was openssl error, I downloaded zip file from https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads and added o my path. And it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac OS then go to the terminal and make sure you are in your directory. The best steps to do are the following:

- `composer update`
- `php artisan migrate`
- `php artisan passport:install`

Answer (score 0):

make sure yours storage directory is accessible and generate keys:

```
php artisan passport:keys
```